# JSON.parse : why this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a JSON :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        success: function (result) {
             var data = JSON.parse(result);
             for (var i = 0; i < data.poles.length; i++) {
             ....
```

What i see in debugger is that :

```
data = "{"poles":[{"id":36,"name":"AUVERGNE"},{"id":44,"name":"Alsace"},{"id":42,"name":"Artois"},....],"poleNumber":48}
```

But i get a message saying that data.poles is not defined

What do i miss?

Comment: I assume `data` is a string and you just used the wrong type of string literals. If it's a string, then it's obviously not an object.

Comment: Why is `{` in quotes?  I think your quotes are inverted.  `poles` should be in quotes, your brackets should not be.  I would think your object would actually be correct if you just removed the first `"` before your first `{`.

Comment: I've edited my message to give the full context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Json ok?

```
{"poles":[{"id":36,"name":"AUVERGNE"},{"id":44,"name":"Alsace"},{"id":42,"name":"Artois"}],"poleNumber":48}
```

EDIT:

Ok, if you have this JSON:

```
data = {"poles":[{"id":36,"name":"AUVERGNE"},{"id":44,"name":"Alsace"},{"id":42,"name":"Artois"}],"poleNumber":48}
```

you can make data.poles perfectly. delete the first ", you have a wrong json, so you will never parse

```
"{"poles":[{"id":36,"name":"AUVERGNE"},{"id":44,"name":"Alsace"},{"id":42,"name":"Artois"}],"poleNumber":48}
```

Comment: oh i see, you mean i'm not supposed to get the first double quote before {

Comment: yes, exactly. you have to delete the first double quot

Comment: ah yes you're right, i had a double gson.toJson() on WS side ^^